# Can you use a disabled form for DetailsView?

Tags: django

I use a lot of class based views in Django in my project. In particular, I find that it is very troublesome to create `model_detail.html`.

Django has the ability to create a form for a model (ModelForm). Is it possible to render the ModelForm for an object but with all inputs disabled in *model*_detail.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within the form itself in your view before sending it to template:

```
form.fields['field_name'].widget.attrs["disabled"] = "disabled"
```

Or with a JS, by assigning the form an ID:

```
$("#id_form input").attr('disabled',true);
```